# How can I encrypt/decrypt in java and encrypt/decrypt in python? I've tried with Libsodium library

Tags: java, android, python, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt data with AES algorytm using Libsodium library(https://download.libsodium.org/doc/) on Android. I've several problems. The first one is understanding the library, I can't find a clear explenation of Java implementation of the library, if I don't know how is meant to be used the algorytm with this library I can not use it. Back to the question: can I possibly do that? Should I use implementation of the same algorythm on booth languages or should I find cross-language library like libsodium so that I know that algorytm is implemented the same way?

Answer (score 2):

The AES algorithm is standardized, but the way it should be used is not. So either you have to design your own protocol or you can use an existing protocol. Using AES securely can be tricky, so in general using a library should be preferred. However, sometimes libraries / container formats cannot be validated to be secure or they may not be sufficient for the specific use case. In that case there is nothing to it but to implement and possibly design a protocol yourself.

You might want to have a look at Fernet, which is also implemented in Java for Java 8.